# Why does padding effectively create a min-width and min-height, even with box-sizing set to border-box, and how to deal with it?

Tags: css

A div with padding can't be made smaller than its padding will allow.

Is this expected behaviour? If so, how can we deal with it?

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 1px; /* Why won't it? */
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: grey;
  animation: animate-width 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes animate-width {
    0% { width: 50px }
   50% { width:  1px }
  100% { width: 50px }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div style="padding: 0"></div>
```

Comment: yes it's the behavior, and you want to deal with what?

Comment: What is `1x`? There’s no such unit.

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behaviour. BTW, whenever possible, try animating transforms, it's much better for performance. You might try using scaleX(0) for the given case, and that will also "fix" your padding issue.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to consider a parent element that you can force to have a width equal to 0 and hide the overflow:

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: animate-width 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  background:red;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.parent > div {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: grey;
  min-width:0;
  width:100%;
}

@keyframes animate-width {
  0% {
    width: 50px
  }
  50% {
    width: 1px
  }
  100% {
    width: 50px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"><div></div></div>
<div class="parent"><div style="padding: 0"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's expected behaviour - padding is a part of an elements dimensions. Re "how can we deal with it": In your particular case, you can also animate the padding:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 1px;
  /* Why won't it? */
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: grey;
  animation: animate-width 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes animate-width {
  0% {
    width: 50px
  }
  50% {
    width: 1px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 50px
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div style="padding: 0"></div>
```